# Converting a SVG command to CoreGraphics

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, svg

I am looking at a SVG file saved from Illustrator.

And I see this line

```
<ellipse transform="matrix(-0.8796 -0.4758 0.4758 -0.8796 674.7629 282.6046)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="373.15" cy="55.9" rx="58.003" ry="55.9"/>
```

I am trying to draw this using CoreGraphics

```
NSGraphicsContext * currentContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
CGContextRef      ctx     = (CGContextRef) [currentContext graphicsPort];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);

CGRect ellipseRect = CGRectMake(373.15 - 58.003 ,55.9 + 55.9 ,58.003 * 2.0 , 55.9 *2.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,ellipseRect.origin.x,self.bounds.size.height -ellipseRect.origin.y);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(ellipseRect.origin.x,self.bounds.size.height -ellipseRect.origin.y,ellipseRect.size.width,ellipseRect.size.height));
CGContextClosePath(ctx);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGContextDrawPath(ctx,kCGPathStroke);
```

this draws the ellipse but not the way it was drawen in illustrator becaus I am not applying the transform.

Now I am trying to apply the transform. So I am doing this

```
NSGraphicsContext * currentContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
CGContextRef      ctx     = (CGContextRef) [currentContext graphicsPort];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);

CGRect ellipseRect = CGRectMake(373.15 - 58.003 ,55.9 + 55.9 ,58.003 * 2.0 , 55.9 *2.0);
CGAffineTransform  affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(-0.8796, -0.4758, 0.4758, -0.8796, 674.7629, 282.6046);
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGFloat radians = atan2f(affineTransform.b, affineTransform.a);
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, degrees);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0-affineTransform.tx,0-affineTransform.ty);

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,ellipseRect.origin.x,self.bounds.size.height -ellipseRect.origin.y);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(ellipseRect.origin.x,self.bounds.size.height -ellipseRect.origin.y,ellipseRect.size.width,ellipseRect.size.height));

CGContextClosePath(ctx);

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx,kCGPathStroke);
```

This rotates the ellipse but not the right way I don't really th transform can anyone explain how I apply the Transformation Matrix?

I know that there are a few SVG Rendering Librarys out there but it is not suiteble for what I am doing.

Comment: May be you are not interpreting the transform matrix right. My math is a bit rusty now, but try to search for a reference on 2D transform matrices. It shuld be 2x2 for scale/rotate/shear and 3x3 (homogeneous coords) if you want to be able to translate as well. Your matrix from SVG has 6 components; I don't know SVG at all so no idea what those are.

Comment: Also, a common mistake could be applying rotation and translation in the wrong order; the two possibilities tipically yield different results.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `CGContextRotateCTM`, `CGContextTranslateCTM` and `CGContextMoveToPoint`. Those are methods for creating a transform. You already have the transform created (`CGAffineTransformMake`). You just need to apply it - probably with `CGRectApplyAffineTransform`.

Comment: Paul that is what I want to do but I cant find the API call for that the function CGRectApplyAffineTransform dose not take a take a context and return only a rect which i dont think I want

Comment: I found that CGContextConcatCTM is much closer but some of the numbers coming from the sag file needs covering so if you know I would be grateful

Comment: Sorry The values coming in the svg file needs to be converted int to quartz coordinate system

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have been programming for windows too many years and the mac coordinate system is different so by adding this line of code it just works

```
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0f * scaleX, -1.0f * scaleY);
```

The scale values is there so you can also scale the graphic